# python selenium geckodriver - executable needs to be in PATH / how to install on armbian buster

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, armbian

When I try to create a Selenium Firefox Webdriver on my Orange Pi with Armbian Buster like

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    
options = Options()
options.headless = True    
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

the exception

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

is thrown. This happens when I use the last `geckodriver` build for ARMv7 from [github](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0) and when I build the `geckodriver` according to [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/ARM.html).

The `geckodriver` binary lies in `/usr/local/bin/` and is executable, but when I try to

```
geckodriver --version
```

I get

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: No such file or directory
```

which leads my to the assumption that there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach. So how do I install `geckodriver` correctly on the Orange Pi with Armbian Buster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by downloading the latest Ubuntu ARM64 [package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/arm64/firefox-geckodriver/) for `firefox-geckodriver`, extracting the `geckodriver` binary and placing it in `/usr/local/bin`. This is also way faster than compiling the `geckodriver` myself and provides the most recent `geckodriver` release.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/.

No Hassle of providing the path of Geckodriver. This will do that for you.

Comment: Does this provide a binaries for ARM64 aswell?

Comment: Ok, this will not work since webdriver_manager only downloads the latest the x64 version from github, so a `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/root/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.27.0/geckodriver'` exception is thrown

Comment: For now there is no official ARM64 geckodriver releases. So webdriver-manager has no possibilities to download ARM64 drivers which are not released officially. And it cant't build them yet. https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/200