# ARM64 Geckodriver for Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, dockerfile, geckodriver, arm64

I require an ARM64 version of geckodriver for Linux.
I am aware you can compile it yourself, however I have no idea how to do that.

I have also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278632/python-selenium-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-how-to-install-on)... if you look at the accepted answer, it is exactly what I need, but is not explained in detail as I am not a linux user. I have downloaded the tar.xz (specifically, [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/firefox/91.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1/firefox_91.0.2+build1.orig.tar.xz) archive) file and extracted it so far, but am unable to locate the Geckodriver within the archive.

Can someone tell me the path to find Geckodriver within this archive and how I can move that into /usr/bin location.
Failing that, any information on how to compile my own Geckodriver using a Dockerfile.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anyone having this same issue try this process step by step.

### A) Install Firefox

```
sudo apt install firefox
firefox --version
```

### B) geckodriver - For arm64

```
sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver
```

### C) Install selenium

```
pip3 install selenium
pip3 install --upgrade requests
```

### D) Script to test

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get('https://google.com/')
print('Title: %s' % browser.title)
time.sleep(2)
browser.quit()
```

** Tested & working on Ubuntu v20 & arm64